# How to implement an ASP.Net Core API Controller which allows Bearer Token authentication OR api key authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I would like to create a Web API that can be accessed either using a Bearer token **OR** a simple API Key, for API key see https://gist.github.com/GeorgDangl/87db6426962bf50933b093e0952570e1.    I understand how to implement both approaches individually however my question is how do I apply an Authorize attribute to my controller class that allows either of these methods.  My understanding is the that Authorise attributes are accumulative ie if I apply both it will mean the request requires a Bear token **AND** an API key.  I want it to work so that if the request has a Bearer token **OR** an API key then it authenticates successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use a single authorization policy that specifies different authentication schemes and authenticating successfully with *one* of those will be enough to continue at which point the requirements of the authorization policy are checked for authorization.

When the authorization happens, the logic used by both the authorization middleware and the authorize filter looks like this (slightly simplified):

```
var authenticateResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, httpContext);

if (HasAllowAnonymous(context))
    return;

var authorizeResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(
        policy, authenticateResult, httpContext, context);

if (authorizeResult.Challenged)
    // trigger Challenge (401)
else if (authorizeResult.Forbidden)
    // trigger Forbid (403)
```

First, the [policy evaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.policy.policyevaluator?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is asked to authenticate the user for the policy, and then the returned result is being used to authorize the user. [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.policy.policyevaluator.authenticateasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the policy evaluator works like this:

1. For each `AuthenticationScheme` in the policy, try to authenticate the user.
2. For all succeeded authentications, merge their user principals into a single principal.
3. Policy authentication was successful if a principal was created, i.e. **at least** one authentication was successful.

So in this process, all authentication schemes will be used to authenticate the user. They can be authenticated through only one scheme, e.g. `Bearer` and `ApiKey`, or they could even be authenticated through multiple schemes.

Then, the policy evaluator [authorizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.policy.policyevaluator.authorizeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) the user, by simply calling the authorization service to [authorize the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationservice.authorizeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_IAuthorizationService_AuthorizeAsync_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_System_Object_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_IAuthorizationRequirement__) against the [policy’s **requirements**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicy.requirements?view=aspnetcore-3.1). And the policy requirements does not contain the authentication scheme that you hae built the policy with.

So to summarize: No, the authentication schemes you pass to the AuthorizationPolicyBuilder are only used for authentication, but not for authorization, and they will be all used to potentially authenticate the user.